# Allow sending email to multiple recipients in ASP.NET with loop and database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email

I am using ASP.NET and SQL Server to send email to multiple recipients with loop. But there is an error here. I have find my solution from internet but still can't solve it.

Here is the error shown:

```
var toAddress = mm.To.Add(email);
```

Here is my `.aspx` file code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="push_notification_admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assignment.push_notification_admin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function alertme() {
                Swal.fire(
                    "The Email Successfully Sent!" ,
                      'success'
                    )
                   
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .error {
            color: red;
            background-image: url("../images/error.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .auto-style1 {
            height: 33px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>Push Notification:</h2>
            <div>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Subject"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter subjuct!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Content"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="auto-style1"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter content!" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `aspx.cs` file code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Security;    

namespace Assignment
{
    public partial class push_notification_admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Notification", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();

            SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");

            while (reader.Read()){
                emailArray.Add(reader["Notice_email"]);
            }
            foreach (string email in emailArray) {

                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(smtpSection.From, "sender@gmail.com"))
                {
                    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
                    var fromAddress = "inpuzzle2021@gmail.com";

                    // any address where the email will be sending
                     var toAddress = mm.To.Add(email);

                    //Password of your gmail address
                    const string fromPassword = "inpuzzlepwd";

                    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
                    string subject = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
                    string body = TextBox2.Text.ToString();

                    // smtp settings
                    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
                    }

                    // Passing values to smtp object
                    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I will be appreciate if someone could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the error and where does it occur?

Comment: Could you explain what is the exact error are you getting, you have not mentioned the error details, if you update with proper details then it will be easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest coding and I have solve it!
The coding that I change to fix it  are:
**emailArray.Add(reader["Notice_email"].ToString());**
and
**var toAddress = email;**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Security;


namespace Assignment
{
    public partial class push_notification_admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Notification", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlDataReader reader;
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList emailArray = new ArrayList();

            SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");

            while (reader.Read()){
                emailArray.Add(reader["Notice_email"].ToString());
            }
            foreach (string email in emailArray) {

                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(smtpSection.From, "sender@gmail.com"))
                {
                    // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
                    var fromAddress = "inpuzzle2021@gmail.com";

                    // any address where the email will be sending
                    var toAddress = email;

                    //Password of your gmail address
                    const string fromPassword = "inpuzzlepwd";

                    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
                    string subject = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
                    string body = TextBox2.Text.ToString();

                    // smtp settings
                    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
                    }

                    // Passing values to smtp object
                    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add method of mm.To is void. i.e. the method returns nothing and hence you cannot assign it to a variable. so your code should be just `mm.To.Add(email);`. This should fix the error you see.

Comment: Hi, I have try it but another error occur,  Here is the line: smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);     "toAddress" is underline with red